# ETL - Update Tables with potentially new records or updated records

Tags: sql, etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to accomplish the following table update via an insert for an etl process:

1. Add in a new records that did not exists
2. Update any records that had updates
3. Keep all the records in place that did not change

On the table I have a unique_id and an updated_date field when the record was updated ( or could serve as the date it was first created). Below is example code of two tables and a third I would want the output to be after an insert statement:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

/* Create a table called NAMES */
CREATE TABLE NAMES(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text, updated_date DATE);
CREATE TABLE NEW_NAMES(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text, updated_date DATE);
CREATE TABLE FINAL_TABLE_DESIRED(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text, updated_date DATE);
/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(1,'Tom', '2021-08-09');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(2,'Lucy', '2021-08-07');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(3,'Frank', '2021-08-07');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(4,'Jane', '2021-08-07');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(5,'Robert', '2021-08-07');


INSERT INTO NEW_NAMES VALUES(1,'Tom John', '2021-08-17');
INSERT INTO NEW_NAMES VALUES(70,'Lollah', '2021-08-07');


INSERT INTO FINAL_TABLE_DESIRED  VALUES(2,'Lucy', '2021-08-07');
INSERT INTO FINAL_TABLE_DESIRED  VALUES(3,'Frank', '2021-08-07');
INSERT INTO FINAL_TABLE_DESIRED  VALUES(4,'Jane', '2021-08-07');
INSERT INTO FINAL_TABLE_DESIRED  VALUES(5,'Robert', '2021-08-07');
INSERT INTO FINAL_TABLE_DESIRED  VALUES(1,'Tom John', '2021-08-17');
INSERT INTO FINAL_TABLE_DESIRED  VALUES(70,'Lollah', '2021-08-17');

COMMIT;

/* Display all the records from the table */
SELECT * FROM  final_table_desired;
```

is there a better approach than the above ie an scd2 - if so why?

Comment: In your code you've physically typed out the code so it doesn't make too much sense to take this approach. How did you match the record with `1 Tom John` with `1 Tom`? You did this in your head and typed it as an insert statement - obviously a computer can't do this! ... As others have mentioned, a `merge` statement is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the MERGE statement to accomplish this

```
MERGE INTO NAMES
USING NEW_NAMES
ON NEW_NAMES.ID = NAMES.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET NAMES.NAME = NEW_NAMES.NAME, UPDATED_DATE = CURRENT_DATE()
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ID, NAME, UPDATED_DATE) VALUES (NEW_NAMES.ID, NEW_NAMES.NAME, CURRENT_DATE());
```

Comment: what if I wanted to update all the columns rather than just names - and I do not want to have to list all the names, as well I want to use the update_date that is origination from the new record (from new_names) not timestamp it

Comment: added update to my question with a proposed alternative if you have any thoughts  @Maja F.

Comment: whether you use SCD1 or SCD2 depends on the business requirements, there is no general answer

Comment: if you want to update all the columns and do not want to list all of them, you can write a stored procedure that will generate the SQL statement for you by getting the column names from INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Create table FINAL_TABLE_DESIRED as a clone of NAMES
2. Write a MERGE INTO statement with FINAL_TABLE_DESIRED as your target and NEW_NAMES as your source

Comment: added update to my question with a proposed alternative if you have any thoughts @NickW

Comment: Please can you explain in what way my proposed solution doesn’t meet your requirements? Not sure what your update to the question is but if it is the comment about SCD2 I’m not sure how that is relevant as the result you’ve said you want to achieve has got nothing to do with SCD2s?